# Observable FromEventPattern INotifyCollectionChanged Bug

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, system.reactive

I have been trying to figure out how to do this. When I have a custom control that I am trying to watch collection changes in the controls ItemsSource. I want to use Reactive Extensions so I can easily dispose of the event watching and avoid the complex weak event pattern. When my ItemsSource is set to a ListCollectionView (From CollectionViewSource in xaml) or a ReadOnlyObservableCollection the FromEventPattern throws an error:
"Could not find event 'CollectionChanged' on object of type 'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView'."
These classes hide the INotifyCollectionChanged by explicitly implementing INotifyCollectionChanged.
Here is my Code. Is this a bug in Reactive Extensions or am I doing it wrong?

```
 IDisposable WatchCollection(INotifyCollectionChanged inc)
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<INotifyCollectionChanged, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(inc, "CollectionChanged").Subscribe(ep =>
        {
            ItemsChanged();
            Refresh();

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Events.cs#L191).

The correct implementation should be:

```
private static IObservable<EventPattern<TSender, TEventArgs>> FromEventPattern_<TSender, TEventArgs>(object target, string eventName, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return FromEventPattern_<TSender, TEventArgs, EventPattern<TSender, TEventArgs>>(typeof(TSender), target, eventName, (sender, args) => new EventPattern<TSender, TEventArgs>(sender, args), scheduler);
}
```

Filed [issue 1239](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1239).

In the meantime, you can change it to:

```
return Observable
    .FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
        e => inc.CollectionChanged += e, 
        e => inc.CollectionChanged -= e)
    .Subscribe(ep =>
    {
        ItemsChanged();
        Refresh();
    });
```

Comment: The same happens with the plain (non-generic) Observable.FromEventPattern(object sender, string event) method. There is a deeper problem where explicitly implemented interface events are not being found or searched for.

Comment: That one is understandable, because no type information is given other than the type of the sender. But I would expect the API you used to use the provided type instead of the run-time type of the sender. Nevertheless, the alternative I provided is always more performant because it doesn't used, possibly flawed, expensive reflection.